Olympiad number theory problem on Sum of digits
Find all $n \in\Bbb N $ such that
$S(n)=S(2n)=S(3n)=...=S(n^2)$, where $S(n)$ denotes the sum of digits of $n$.
I only got one information: that $9\mid n$ (using the property that $S(n)≡n\bmod9$), and nothing else.
The problem looks easy but I am still unable to solve it. The solutions by some python code I got were $n=10^k-1,\forall k\in\Bbb N$.
Please let me know if you have any ideas to solve it.
Thanks

Clearly this is true for $n = 1$, so your claim that $ 9 \mid n$ needs a bit more work.

I present two general claims which essentially make this question trivial.

Claim $1$: $S(n(10^k-1)) = 9k$ for $1\le n\le 10^k$.

Proof: Write $n=\overline{a_ja_{j-1}\dots a_1}$. Note that one may ignore trailing zero's in $n$ since those zero's do not change the digit sum and so $a_1\neq 0$. Then
$$n(10^k-1) = \overline{a_ja_{j-1}\dots (a_1-1)\underbrace{99\dots 99}_{k-j}(9-a_j)(9-a_{j-1})\dots(10-a_1)}$$
and thus $S(n(10^k-1)) = 9k$.

Claim $2$: Given $j$-digit number $n$ atleast one of whose digits differ from $9$ we have $S(n) \neq S((10^{j-1}+1)n)$ for $j>1$ and $S(n)>9$.

Proof: Write $n=\overline{a_ja_{j-1}\dots a_1}$. Then $$(1+10^{j-1})n = \overline{b_jb_{j-1}\dots b_{1}b_{0}a_{j-1}a_{j-2}\dots a_2a_1}$$
where the $b_i$s are calculated keeping in view that some additions may lead to "carries". We now utilize case work.
Particularly if $a_j+a_1\le 9$ then there occur no carries so that $b_0 = a_j + a_1$, $b_j=0$ and for other indices $b_{i-1}=a_i$. Thus the digit sum is $2S(n)$.
When $a_j+a_1>9$ then there occur carries. However we again divide this case into cases; based on whether $a_2<9$ or $a_2=9$.
Taking $a_2\lt 9$ we have exactly $1$ carry; namely that $b_1 = a_2 + 1$ and that $b_0=a_j+a_1-10$; then $b_j=0$ and for all other indices we have $b_{i-1}=a_i$. Then the digit sum in this case is $2S(n)-9$.
Then when $a_2 = 9$ we use casework on $a_3$ whether it is $=9$ or $\neq 9$. We continue this and conclude that if not all the digits are $9$ then the sum is $\neq S(n)$; otherwise it is $S(n)$.

Using claim $1$ we know that the family $10^k-1$ works for $k\in \mathbb N$. From the second claim we know that for $n$ with more than $1$ digit this is the only form that works. Thus can you conclude the result?

To conclude claim $2$ I did hand-wave a little and skip the details. I hope the reader can recognize so, since it requires only some computation to check.

Good stuff! (+1) My post consists of your claim 2 and an argument,  It is a bit taxing to make the details crystal clear, but once the idea is there, everything does fall into place :-)

Not a full solution in the sense that I haven't thought about an explanation as to why $n=10^k-1$ works (See Sahaj's answer for that direcion). The point of this post is to explain why it is necessary for $n$ to be of that form (excluding the trivial solution $n=1$).
Let $n=d_1d_2\ldots d_r$ be the decimal expansion of such a number. As has been explained, we know that the sum of the digits $d_i, 1\le i\le r$, must be divisible by nine. Of course, I assume that $d_1\ge1$.
A key observation is that unless we have $d_1=d_2=\cdots=d_r=9$, we have $S(n+d_1)>d_1$. Normally $n+d_1$ shares its most signficant digit $d_1$ with $n$, and there will also be another non-zero digit in $n+d_1$, when clearly $S(n+d_1)>d_1$. The rare exceptions are

either $n+d_1\ge (d_1+1)\cdot10^{r-1}$ when an avalanche of carries turned the most significant digit of $n+d_1$ to $d_1+1$,
or $n+d_1\ge 10^r$, in which case the change of the most significant digit caused the number of digits to increase when moving from $n$ to $n+d_1$.

The first case is a non-problem, because then the leading digit is $d_1+1$ and hence $S(n+d_1)>d_1$. The latter case is impossible. For it to happen we must have $$d_1=d_2=\cdots=d_{r-1}=9,$$ and for the addition $d_r+d_1$ to trigger a carry. But in this case we know $d_r$ to be divisible by nine, so (still assuming one of the digits differs from $9$) that leaves $d_r=0$, and hence no carry.
The rest is easy. Namely we can use $m=10^{r-1}+1$. In that case the trailing $r-1$ digits of
$$mn=10^{r-1}n+n$$ are $d_2d_3\ldots d_r$. And the leading $r$ (or $r+1$) digits are those of $n+d_1$. We just saw that the latter produces a digit sum strictly larger than $d_1$, so we have shown that $S(mn)>S(n)$.
Observe that $n\ge m$ unless $n=10^{r-1}$. This is a non-problem unless $r=1=n$.

A few words about, where the choice $m=10^{r-1}+1$ came from. Testing already tells a story. When $n=18$, $m=11$ is the smallest $m$ with the property $S(mn)\neq S(n)$. Similarly with $n=198$ again $m=101$ is the smallest $m$ that fits. Yeah, computers are amazing for experimental math.
The rest of my testing didn't really fit, but only because I was looking for a formula for the smallest $m$ that works! A moment's reflection revealed that if $n<10^r$, then $m=10^r+1$ always yields $S(mn)>S(n)$ because $mn$ simply duplicates the digits of $n$ twice. It's a small step from there :-)

Why does 10^n - 1 work: It has all 9's. If you multiply it by k, then you add k-1 in front of the n digits, and subtrace k-1 from the last digits. There is no carry / borrow, so the sum of digits stays the same.

@gnasher729 Sure. Also see Sahaj's answer. I simply didn't have time to think about it. There was an earlier failed attempt to prove necessity, so I simply worked on that. It may be the more difficult direction anyway.
